# How can I fill an actionscript 3 polygon with a solid color?

Tags: actionscript, polygon, fill, shapes, uicomponents

I'm building a map editor for a project and need to draw a hexagon and fill it with a solid color.  I have the shape correct but for the life of me can't figure out how to fill it.  I suspect it may be due to whether the thing is a Shape, Sprite or UIComponent.  Here is what I have for the polygon itself:

```
import com.Polygon;
import mx.core.UIComponent;

public class greenFillOne extends UIComponent {
    public var hexWidth:Number = 64;
    public var hexLength:Number = 73;

    public function greenFillOne() {
        var hexPoly:Polygon = new Polygon;
        hexPoly.drawPolygon(40,6,27+(hexWidth*.25),37,0x499b0e,1,30);
        addChild(hexPoly);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have access to the code of com.Polygon class, add a graphics.beginFill(color, alpha) before the drawing starts.

Comment: I tried doing that, using the com.polygon class.  While it still rendered the outline of the hex, it wouldn't fill the hex.  I tried several places, including adding the fill information to polygon.as but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6):

The Polygon class isn't a standard Adobe library, so I don't know the specifics. However, assuming that it uses the standard flash API, it should be no problem to add some code to extend the function. You just need to make sure you're doing a `graphics.beginFill` before the  `graphics.lineTo` / `graphics.moveTo` functions. And then finish with `graphics.endFill`.

e.g.,

```
var g:Graphics = someShape.graphics;
g.beginFill(0xFF0000,.4); // red, .4 opacity 
g.moveTo(x1,y1);
g.lineTo(x2,y2);
g.lineTo(x3,y3);
g.lineTo(x1,y1);
g.endFill();
```

This will draw a triangle filled with .4 red.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this here because answering it as a comment to Glenn goes past the character limit.  My actionscript file extends UIComponent.  When I created a variable hexPoly:Polygon = new Polygon; it would render the outline of the hex, but would not fill it no matter what I did.  I examined polygon.as and duplicated the methods, but as a sprite and it worked.  So, I need to figure out how to wrap the polygon as a sprite, or just leave it as is.

```
var hexPoly:Sprite = new Sprite;
hexPoly.graphics.beginFill(0x4ea50f,1);
hexPoly.graphics.moveTo(xCenter+(hexWidth*.25)+Math.sin(radians(330))*radius,offset+(radius-Math.cos(radians(330))*radius));
hexPoly.graphics.lineTo(xCenter+(hexWidth*.25)+Math.sin(radians(30))*radius,offset+(radius-Math.cos(radians(30))*radius));
hexPoly.graphics.lineTo(xCenter+(hexWidth*.25)+Math.sin(radians(90))*radius,offset+(radius-Math.cos(radians(90))*radius));
hexPoly.graphics.lineTo(xCenter+(hexWidth*.25)+Math.sin(radians(150))*radius,offset+(radius-Math.cos(radians(150))*radius));
hexPoly.graphics.lineTo(xCenter+(hexWidth*.25)+Math.sin(radians(210))*radius,offset+(radius-Math.cos(radians(210))*radius));
hexPoly.graphics.lineTo(xCenter+(hexWidth*.25)+Math.sin(radians(270))*radius,offset+(radius-Math.cos(radians(270))*radius));
hexPoly.graphics.endFill();
addChild(hexPoly);
```